# subclass the ui.autocomplete jquery

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, subclass

I extend the Query UI widget autcomplete like this:

http://jsbin.com/icota4/15/edit

But i can't success to use methode change , select... without declare them in the html, all use of the new widget are identical so i want declare the function in the javascript.

(with the ui autocomplete if i don't declare them in the html, the code use function in the ui widget)

so when i select item in the console i must see : 
ici and the value of the variable text, but nothing append.

How i can solve my problems.

Thank a lot

Answer (score 0):

I success with the method change like this in the _create:

```
this.element.live('change', function() {

    if (self.options.blur_clear_input) {
        clear_input(false);
    } else {
        var text = $("#autocomplete_input").val();
        if (self.options.multiple || self.options.token_alone) {
            self._create_token(text);
        } else {
            $('#autocomplete_input_true').val(text);
        }
    }
});
```

But I try to do the same with select but it doesn't work. Someone know where is the problem?